# EC2 instance details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am new to AWS, I want to export all my ec2 instance information to a csv file.

I would like to export, Name, instance id, Instance Type, Availability zone, OS, VPC, Subnet, state, Private IP, Public IP, Security group, Keypair, and AMI id.

Will the below syntax work for me? I'd like to add OS, VPC, Subnet, Security group, Keypair, AMI id

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query
"Reservations[*].Instances[*].[
   InstanceId, 
   InstanceType, 
   ImageId, 
   State.Name, 
   LaunchTime, 
   Placement.AvailabilityZone, 
   Placement.Tenancy, 
   PrivateIpAddress, 
   PrivateDnsName, 
   PublicDnsName, 
   [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value] [0][0], 
   [Tags[?Key==`Role`].Value] [0][0], 
   [Tags[?Key==`SysHostName`].Value] [0][0], 
   [Tags[?Key==`Product`].Value] [0][0], 
   [Tags[?Key==`Project`].Value] [0][0] 
 ]" > C:\instances.csv
```

Comment: Did you try? Was the output as expected?

Comment: You might also consider using [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html), which maintains much of this information for you.

Comment: I did not try also i need to add OS, VPC, Subnet, Security group, Keypair, AMI id to the syntax which i am not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    import boto3
    import csv
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    ec2_re = session.resource(service_name="ec2", region_name="us-east-1")
    cnt=1
    csv_ob=open("inventory_info_v1.csv","w",newline='')
    csv_w=csv.writer(csv_ob)
    csv_w.writerow(["S_NO", 'AWS Instance ID', 'AWS Account', 'IP Address', 
    'VPC', 'OS', 'AMI', 'AWS Instance Type', 'Security Group'])
    
    sts = session.client(service_name="sts",region_name="us-east-1")
    response = sts.get_caller_identity()
    account = response.get('Account')
    
    for each_item in ec2_re.instances.all():
        id = each_item.instance_id
        ip = each_item.private_ip_address
        vpc = each_item.vpc_id
        os = each_item.platform_details
        ami = each_item.image_id
        type = each_item.instance_type
        sglist = each_item.security_groups
        for item in sglist:
            sgid = item['GroupId']
    
        print(cnt, id, account, ip, vpc, os, ami, type, sgid)
        csv_w.writerow([cnt, id, account, ip, vpc, os, ami, type, sgid])
        cnt+=1
    
    csv_ob.close()
```

This will work.You will get all the details in .csv format.